# Translating "to make money"

Tags: traducción

I have been wondering how to translate "to make money" in speaking and writing in Spanish

From what I know it would be translated like this:

> "The man made 100 dollars last year"
>
> El hombre hizo cien dólares el año pasado.

Is this correct? If not what is the correct way to state "to make money" and be sure to give some examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, in Spanish we say **"ganar dinero"** as to *earn money*. That is, in a context when you explain someone's profession or activity:

> She earns a lot of money as a nurse
>
> Ella gana mucho dinero como enfermera

If we want to express that someone made some money by doing something punctual, we use verbs like **"sacar"** in an informal context:

> She made 100€ by selling ice creams in the beach
>
> Ella se sacó 100€ vendiendo helados en la playa

Comment: ¿Sería incorrecto usar ganarse en este caso?

Comment: @aris no me suena demasiado bien. Como mucho algo así como "ella consiguió ganarse un buen dinero haciendo de enfermera durante el verano".

Answer (score 1):

El diccionario [wordmagic](https://www.wordmagicsoft.com/dictionary/en-es/make%20money.php) ofrece las siguientes traducciones para "make money":

- ganar dinero
- hacer dinero
- ganar plata
- hacer plata
- lucrarse
- obtener dinero
- sacar ganancia
- sacar cuartos